# How Do We Test PostInstall Script That Makes PermissionSetAssignment?

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests, postinstall

I'm missing something obvious but we have a PostInstall script that makes a PermissionSetAssignment to the installer to give an Admin permission. The test class is failing since, as is documented in [Salesforce InstallHandler Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_install_handler.htm), the special install user is not accessible in tests.

The error is on the `insert psalist`;

So how do I test that the InstallHandler successfully assigned the Permission Set? Thought of a Login Flow but given that this runs everytime a user logs in its overkill for a one-time process and is the purpose of having a Post Install script.

```
    global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
        Map<String, Object> inputs = new Map<String, Object>();
        if (context.previousVersion() == null) {
            // ID of user installing package. Part of InstallHandler Interface
            Id UserId = context.installerId();

            // Getting System Administrator PermissionSet
            List<PermissionSet> PermissionSetToAssignList = [
                SELECT Id, Name
                FROM PermissionSet
                WHERE Name = 'provNpiAdministrator' AND NamespacePrefix = 'prov'
            ];

            List<PermissionSetAssignment> psalist = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
            PermissionSet PermissionSetToAssign = PermissionSetToAssignList[0];
            PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment();
            psa.PermissionSetId = PermissionSetToAssign.Id;
            psa.AssigneeId = UserId;
            psalist.add(psa);

            insert psalist;
        } else if (context.isUpgrade()) {
        }
        if (context.isPush()) {
        }
    }
}
```

```
@isTest
class PostInstallClassNpiTest {
    @isTest
    static void onInstallTest() {
        PostInstallClassNpi postinstall = new PostInstallClassNpi();
        Test.testInstall(postinstall, null);
        List<PermissionSetAssignment> psa = [
            SELECT id, PermissionSetId
            FROM PermissionSetAssignment
            WHERE PermissionSet.Name = 'provNpiAdministrator'
        ];
        System.assertEquals(psa.size(), 1, 'PermissionSetAssignment found');
        // Test.testInstall(postinstall, new Version(1, 0), true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're meant to set up a context user first. Here's a trivial example I wrote.

```
@isTest class installerTest {
    @isTest static void test() {
        User u = [select Fields(standard) from user where isactive=true limit 1];
        u = u.clone(false, false, false);
        u.username=u.username+'1';
        u.FederationIdentifier=null;
        u.Alias+='1';
        u.CommunityNickname+='1';
        System.runas(u) {
            Test.startTest();
            Test.testInstall(new OnInstallH(), null);
            System.assertEquals(UserInfo.getUserId(), storage.userId);
        }
        System.assertNotEquals(UserInfo.getUserId(), storage.userId);
    }
}
```

Where `storage.userId` is just a static variable somewhere for testing.

This runs without error, so presumably it should be safe to say that your code should be able to create a test user, assign it a particular profile, and then have that user run the install, which shouldn't fail during testing.

Comment: This is probably what was needed but I ended up using a Flow instead for postinstall actions.